# How to hide uncategorized on different languages

Tags: php, wordpress, code-snippets, wpml

I tried code below to hide a Uncategorized category, but in others languages this category is visible, how to fix it

```
function my_product_subcategories_arg( $args ) {
    $uncategorized = get_option( 'default_product_cat' );
    $args['exclude'] = $uncategorized;
    $args['hide_empty'] = 0;
    return $args;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_subcategories_args', 'my_product_subcategories_arg', 10, 1 );
```

Answer (score 0):

So for all other categories it works? If yes then pick a different category that you don't need to hide and make it default:

- In wp-admin go to *Settings > Writing*
- Find *Default Post Category* drop-down and select any other category other than Uncategorized, save changes.

Comment: This is not an option. Since there are products that we sell in a set and should not be purchased separately by customers.

Answer (score 0):

This helped me:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_product_categories_widget_args', 'exclude_category');
function exclude_category($args) {
$args['exclude'] = array('15');
        return $args;
}
```